# In Kotlin what does this get() do

Tags: kotlin

Im new to Kotlin  and wonder what does the `get() = login_email.txt.toString()` do?

Does it set `email` String?

[image]

Comment: do not post code as image

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`get()` and `set(value)` after a field means the declaration of a custom getter and/or setter. Here's a basic example using default values:

```
class Demo{
    var something: String
        get() = field
        set(value) {
            field = value;
        }
    constructor(something: String){
        this.something = something;
    }
}
```

These two are, however, redundant. You don't actually need them unless you're doing something custom with it. They're automatically added for vars, though that only applies to getters for `val`s (because they can't be changed, they don't have setters).

The line you were asking about is a custom getter.

```
get() // declares a custom getter
    = // if you don't know how this works, see my explanation below
    login_email.text.toString() // you should be familiar with this part already; gets the string value of the field
```

If you're not familiar with the syntax, this is the equivalent without `=`:

```
get(){
    return login_email.text.toString()
}
```

if you have a single return, you can replace the brackets and return keyword with `=`. If it helps you remember, just remember the alternative to using `=` (a body + the `return` keyword)

**TL;DR:** it declares a custom setter that returns the value of a TextView/EditText (not sure which it is, you didn't include that in the question)

---

In your case, you're using a custom getter or setter to handle property data. The fields themselves don't actually contain any data, but you have getters for a different object.

Take this as an example:

```
class Demo(private val someObject: MyCustomObjectWithSomeData){
    val text: String
        get() = someObject.text
    ... same for other stuff. Could also have setters, if the properties are mutable
}
```

Here the object is private, but it could be public or internal for that matter.

Kotlin supports quite a lot with custom getters. For an instance, you can declare a field to display specific fields of a private variable. For an instance, in your case, you have the email. It doesn't need to be a variable, since you have a custom getter, and the field isn't initialized. If you change `var email` to a `val`, you can make it non-null:

```
val email: String
    get() = login_email.text.toString()
```

That also helps with null-safety.

And for the `error` field, it's slightly more complicated. It can't be a `val` because you declare a custom setter, but if you add a getter, you can make it non-null:

```
var error: String
    get() = login_error.text.toString()
    set(value){
        login_error.text = value;
    }
```

Comment: Lets say i write : public val customObj get() = MyCustomClass(), what it does is creates a new object every time customObj is accessed from other classes  ?

Comment: @SumukhaAithalK you pointed on an interesting part and the answer is yes. It's similar to have `public MyCustomClass get() { return new MyCustomClass(); }` in Java

Answer (score 3):

#### Short Answer

- `get()` is used to define a custom getter method. Anytime you access the property you are using the custom getter method

#### Long Answer

- So before we can talk about `get()`, it is important that we get a proper understanding of what `properties` actually are.

##### Properties

- We all know that in object oriented programming the main idea of a class is to encapsulate data and code that works on data in a single class. In a language like Java (don't worry we will get back to Kotlin soon), the data of a class is stored in private fields, we then use accessor method (getters and setters) to access the data. In Java the combination of accessor methods and a field is called a `property`
- Now in Kotlin does things a little differently, it entirely replaces the traditional idea of defining accessor methods and fields. By using the `val` or `var` keyword Kotlin will automatically generate the corresponding field and appropriate accessor methods for us.

##### get()

- There will come a time when either your code or someone else's code needs a more robust solution to the automatic accessor methods created by Kotlin. This is where `get()` and `set()` come into play. By using get() you are defining your own custom accessor method(getter for get()) to be used when you are accessing this property.
- I would also like to point out that since `val` is immutable it does not allow you to define a `set()` method, only a `get()`