# Kotlin: Initialisation and get for a variable

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between:

```
1.
    var abc = someObject.getSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently()
    
    vs 
  
2.  
    var abc = someObject.getSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently()
       get = someObject.getSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently()
```

someObject.getSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently() changes frequently.
Will using the first way, only set the value at init and then always return that value from abc regardless of what value is later returned by someObject.getSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently()
or will abc always return the latest value of someObject.getSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently().

I don't want to #2 coz then i have to call someObject.getSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently() in both init of the abc and in get()

please advice. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Kotlin what does this get() do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570254/in-kotlin-what-does-this-get-do)

Comment: sorry it doesnt

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to #2 coz then i have to call someObject.getSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently() in both init of the abc and in get()

What you should write instead is

```
val abc
   get() = someObject.getSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently()
```

or

```
var abc
   get() = someObject.getSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently()
   set(value) = someObject.setSomeValueWhichChangesFrequently(value)
```

The call in the initializer in your #2 is actually useless, because it initializes the [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields), but the getter never accesses it.