# What is this "get0" syntax in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Confused this "get()" usage. Any document talks about this usage?

```
    val intList: List<Int> get() = concurrentLinkedQueue.toList()
```

Comment: It's a custom 'getter' - a way of telling Kotlin what to return when someone refers to `intList` as a property. Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570254/in-kotlin-what-does-this-get-do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the confusion around the `get()` syntax in Kotlin. In the provided code snippet:

```
val intList: List<Int> get() = concurrentLinkedQueue.toList()
```

Here's what's happening:

`val intList` : declares a read-only property named intList.

`List<Int>` : specifies the type of the property, indicating that it will hold a list of integers.

`get()` : is a property accessor. In Kotlin, you can customize how a property is accessed using the `get()` function. In this case, when someone accesses `intList`, it's not just a straightforward property access; instead, the `get()` function is invoked.

`concurrentLinkedQueue.toList()` : is the expression inside the `get()` function. It retrieves the elements from a concurrentLinkedQueue and converts them into a list.
So, whenever someone tries to access `intList`, behind the scenes, it's as if they are calling the `get()` function, which, in turn, returns the list of elements from concurrentLinkedQueue.

Hope this clears up the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

These properties are called "computed properties", since they don't have a backing field: in Java, you'd implement them using methods, rather than fields. You can find more examples in [Properties: Getters and setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters).